# Voting Up on StackOverflow Bug

Tags: support

First Off, I have a rep of 84 points on StackOverflow. For some reason, it saves the upvotes I make on a post. The minimum rep you need to show your upvote publicly is 125 rep. So I believe this is bug because it happened a few times(2).

Comment: You only need 15 reputation to upvote. You need 125 reputation to downvote.

Comment: The only thing I need to say to myself is bakka.

Comment: @narusin Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges, it's got the full list of privileges with descriptions and reputation thresholds. Also, fyi, every site has a /help/privileges where you can find the thresholds for that particular site. Usually I just type the URL directly, the most direct click path I know to get there is a little roundabout (your profile → click the next privilege indicator → learn more → click Privileges in the nav bar on the right -- maybe there's a more direct route).

Comment: Shorter "click" route for any site: Click on "Help", click on "Help Center", at the bottom of the center column, click on "View a full list of privileges you can earn".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You only need 15 reputation to upvote. You need 125 reputation to downvote.

By [@animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292542/voting-up-on-stackoverflow-bug#comment950369_292542).